# What is the Hotkey to show Chrome bookmark bar?

Tags: google-chrome, hotkeys

What is the Hotkey to show Chrome bookmark bar?

Comment: Hey @Nam, just accept one of these fine answers. Don't be afraid, it is really not such a bad experience.

Comment: The settings page refers toggling as "always show", however I doubt any "temporarily show" ever existed, hovering or something with less persistent effect.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See *View » Always Show Bookmarks Bar*.

It's `Cmd-Shift-B` on OS X, I suspect `Ctrl-Shift-B` elsewhere.

Comment: Works on Linux mint 17.

Comment: It's clipy who's using cmd + shift + b. clearing that shortcut now works perfectly.

Comment: @ssi-anik you're a godsend. I was struggling with that. Now everything is fine. Dang Clippy for hijacking that shortcut.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Google Chrome documentation](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95745)

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `B` in Windows and `Cmd` + `Shift` + `B` in Mac OS

Comment: Verified, works in Chrome v20.

Comment: Don't know the reason for posting the same thing in a separate answer.  :/